# Call GameScene method from AppDelegate (Swift 3, SpriteKit, Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, appdelegate

I am using Spritekit and swift 3 for create a game, my problem is when I try to call my `pauseGame()` method, present in my GameScene class (subclass of SKScene), from AppDelegate file within `applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)` method.

I already try to instantiate GameScene class and then call the method in my AppDelegate file in this way, although there is no compiler error it doesn't work:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

        gameScene.pauseGame()
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: applicationwillresignactive sends out a notification, you can listen to it in your game scene class, no need to do the work in app delegate

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you should post that as an answer, not a comment

Comment: @BadgerBadger that would require me to actually write an answer, too lazy to do that

Comment: @Knight0fDragon hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of your GameScene.
To pause the existing instance you need to add a reference to it in the AppDelegate.

The better solution it to register the GameScene class to receive notifications when the app goes into the background. This is a good alternative to coupling these classes with the AppDelegate.

In your GameScene class add this in the viewDidLoad() function:

```
let app = UIApplication.shared

//Register for the applicationWillResignActive anywhere in your app.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameScene.applicationWillResignActive(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: app)
```

Add this function to the GameScene class to react to the received notification:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(notification: NSNotification) {
     pauseGame()
}
```

Comment: I made an edit to change ViewController to GameScene,  for some reason it logged it as anonymous, so if you want to change it you are more than welcome to.